# Overwriting getText of JTextField

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, jtextcomponent

I wish to overwrite `getText()` so that it can return a null value instead of a a blank value. I noticed that `getText()` is a part of `JTextComponent` and I've been unable to successfully overwrite it. What is the best way to get the desired result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can subclass `JTextField` and override the `getText` method, as such

```
public final class JCustomTextField extends JTextField{
    .
    .
    .
    @Override
    public String getText(){
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Or you can inline the override, as such

```
JTextField textField = new JTextField(){
    .
    .
    .
    @Override
    public String getText(){
        // do stuff
    }  
};
```

Comment: Why are you declaring the class as final?

Comment: @Jeffrey, To prevent subclassing. I do that out of habit. :D